# Azure ACS get token using RestSharp 415 error

Tags: c#, http, azure, restsharp

The following is the code sample provided by msdn for obtaining an SWT token from azure ACS (Access Control Service):

```
private static string GetTokenFromACS(string scope)
{
    string wrapPassword = pwd;
    string wrapUsername = uid;

    // request a token from ACS
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.BaseAddress = string.Format(
        "https://{0}.{1}", serviceNamespace, acsHostUrl);

    NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
    values.Add("wrap_name", wrapUsername);
    values.Add("wrap_password", wrapPassword);
    values.Add("wrap_scope", scope);

    byte[] responseBytes = client.UploadValues("WRAPv0.9/", "POST", values);

    string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);

    Console.WriteLine("\nreceived token from ACS: {0}\n", response);

    return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(
        response
        .Split('&')
        .Single(value => value.StartsWith("wrap_access_token=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        .Split('=')[1]);
}
```

I am trying to replicate the code using RestSharp:

```
var request = new RestRequest("WRAPv0.9", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("wrap_name", uid, ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddParameter("wrap_password", pwd, ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddParameter("wrap_scope", realm, ParameterType.RequestBody);

RestClient client = new RestClient(
    string.Format(@"https://{0}.{1}", serviceNamespace, acsHostUrl));

client.ExecuteAsync(request, Callback);
```

I tried other variations of the above code but to no avail. I keep recieving a 415 error stating that:

> 415 Unsupported Media Type T8000 Content-Type 'text/plain' is not
>   supported. The request content type must be
>   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

I am not a Fiddler expert but with my limited experience with it I was not able to inspect my outgoing http request because it is encrypted.

I would appreciate advice on solving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to leave out the `AddHeader` method call and instead set the Content-Type as the first `AddParameter`.
The issue [is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432436/does-restsharp-overwrite-manually-set-content-type).